# Keystrokes are not grabbed by VirtualBox on guest machine

Tags: virtualbox, windows, virtualization

I have a VirtualBox guest machine running Windows 10. 
On my host machine I have Ubuntu 17.04.

When I enter my guest machine, keys like the Super key and alt key are not grabbed so when I press the Super key, it opens the search menu in my host machine... And if I use Alt+Tab, it exits my guest machine window(and switches to another windows)..

I already have the "Auto Capture Keyboard" option on and I've also tried it with this option off..

By the way, it also happens when I'm controlling a remote computer with Teamviewer.. I guess it has something with it.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is really a problem dealing more with Windows and Virtualbox, than Ubuntu.  That said, when I'm running a VM I have identical behaviour until I click once with my mouse inside the VM Window indicating to it that it should take control of the keyboard.  I use KVM/QEMU rather than VB however.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Well, not the case for me..

Comment: It's not an unknown situation for VM - [this example](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=83138&p=393344&hilit=windows+host+capture+keyboard#p393344) is a Fedora host and an Ubuntu guest.  I would suggest that you post this question on the [Virtualbox Forums](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewforum.php?f=6)

Comment: @CharlesGreen I have added new information(about the TeamViewer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was very specific. I'm not sure what was not good, probably something with the installation.. However, when I have reinstalled my host OS, it worked. Now it is working normally..

Answer (score 1):

1. for the <kbd>super key</kbd> to work you need to press it twice - the first key press is caught by Ubuntu, the second one gets through to the guest OS.
2. <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> *might* require the VM to be in full-screen mode

Comment: Doesn't work.. Also, alt+tab doesn't work in full screen mode either

Answer (score 1):

Virtualbox doesn't capture certian modifier key combinations. However, there is a built in alternative.

At the top of the VM window, there is a tab marked "input". Under the keyboard menu is a list of key strokes for the modifiers. Most involve holding the "host key". On my machine the host key is <kbd>Right ctrl</kbd>

Comment: Alt + tab is not one of them though

Comment: Alt-tab works normally in my VirtualBox.  version 5.1.30

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** In my Laptop the <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Windows key</kbd> combination does the trick and it is captured by the virtual machine

Comment: Same for me with the Windows key; how stupid!  Doesn't help for things like Alt-Tab not being captured though :( Edit: [might be related to Wayland](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1285770).

Answer (score 0):

My Dell Latitude E7450 has Ubuntu 17.10 as the host with a Windows 10 guest in VirtualBox (version 5.1.34).  I experience similar issues as @Ben (<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> not working in the guest).

**Solution**: <kbd>windows key</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> cycles through the open programs (i.e., what I expect <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> to do).

Not sure how to get the <kbd>windows key</kbd> to bring up the start menu.